# Are close votes intended to be policy-driven or policy-defining?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

It seems to me that there are, broadly speaking, two ways in which Stack Exchange communities use the close vote system. Obviously these are aspects of community culture that have evolved over time and not the result of any individual's behaviour; but it seems to me that one of them results in a more useful type of site than the other, and I'm wondering if Stack Exchange has any official policy on the way it's supposed to work.

Also, I should say that my division of this issue into two distinct camps is probably a massive oversimplification, but hopefully it will help to get the point across.

Here are the two models I've observed:

---

**Model 1: close votes are strictly for *implementation* of policy**

According to this model, there is a more or less strict rule that close votes should always be cast in line with the community's policy. The policy itself is determined by discussions (and votes) on the site's meta page. When casting a close vote, one should always be able to justify it (if asked) by posting a link to the relevant meta discussion. Casting close votes (or reopen votes) that contradict the agreed policy is seen as a Bad Thing. The community's general view is that if you want to change the policy you should post a discussion on meta, and using close votes to influence policy is seen as cheating. Moderators are active in policing this, by reverting decisions that go against the meta consensus, or by making sure a discussion takes place on meta (and freezing the question in the mean time) in cases where the policy isn't clear.

A good example of a community that takes this view is [Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com). These attitudes can be seen especially in discussions from around 2013-2014 on the physics meta site.

**Model 2: close votes are for both implementing and *determining* policy**

In this model, the close vote system is seen not just as a community implementation of policy, but as a democratic system for determining which systems *should* be closed. Policy is still discussed on meta, but these discussions are less focused towards decision-making, since the decisions are generally left to those community members who are active in the review queues. Policy is justified in terms of which questions have tended to be closed in the past, rather than in terms of explicit decisions on meta. If one disagrees with a question being closed, the standard procedure is to cast a reopen vote. Moderators take a hands-off approach to closing and reopening questions, particularly in cases where a clear policy has not yet been established.

There are many communities that use this model, but I feel it would be less productive to name them. In many ways I think it's the default, though of course I only have experience with a few communities out of the many that exist.

---

For me personally, I tend to feel that in practice, model 1 is far superior to model 2. I understand that others will have different views, and part of the purpose of this question is to figure out whether I'm right in assuming (as I've tended to in the past) that model 1 is the way it's intended to work.

In both types of community, many questions get closed. Closing bad questions is, explicitly, one of Stack Exchange's unique selling points compared to other Q&A sites. I also believe (though I can't recall where I read it) that the scope of a Stack Exchange community is explicitly intended to become narrower as it grows. Because of this, under both models, it's fairly likely that a question from a new user will fall afoul of some rule or convention that isn't immediately obvious from a glance at the FAQ.

However, in a model 1 community the rules are explicitly written down, and a new user can be pointed towards them, thus giving them the ability to understand what needs to be fixed, and to write better questions in the future. If one disagrees that a question should be closed, one can argue on meta that the votes were against policy, and if they were then the question will be reopened. If one disagrees with the policy, one can make the case for changing it.

In contrast, posting as a new user in a model 2 community can be incredibly frustrating. (I'm a scientist in an interdisciplinary domain, hence perhaps I have more experience than most with trying to ask a professional question in a field that is not my own.) The problem is that the rules aren't really written down anywhere, and this makes it almost impossible to predict whether a question will be closed. Being aware of this, I will often put a huge amount of effort into explaining the background to my question, or explaining why it isn't a duplicate of some other superficially similar question, only to have my question closed for some other reason that I couldn't have thought of. It is sometimes possible to have a question reopened (by asking nicely on meta for people to cast reopen votes) but if one feels the policy should be changed to become more open, there is no real way to argue for that.

Moreover, from a design point of view, it doesn't feel to me as if model 2 is the way it was meant to work. The issue is that requiring only five votes means that a small minority of users can easily influence policy in a *negative* direction (i.e. towards disallowing a certain class of question), but it's very hard for anyone to influence policy in a *positive* direction (opening up the site to a new type of question). This seems to me to lead towards a "lowest common denominator" effect whereby the only questions that remain open are those that can be easily understood by everybody, or that fit a tightly defined stereotype that, by convention, is allowed. This means that Stack Exchange sites often lose the "deepest" questions (by which I mean those with the greatest insight, or those that take the most specialised knowledge to answer), along with the low quality ones. This happens particularly on smaller sites (where it's relatively rare for a question to accumulate 5 reopen votes), and it's particularly bad for science-based sites, where entire specialised sub-fields can be edged out, and interdisciplinary questions tend to have no place.

One other minor point is that model 2 seems to be more common than model 1 (on technical sites at least), and there also seems to be something a tendency for communities to move more towards model 2 over time. But I'm basing that on a small sample of communities, so it might not be true.

In conclusion, here are my questions for now:

- Is there any official position on which (if either) of these is the intended way for the system to be used, or has it always been a matter for the community to decide? (Is there something written about this on the Stack Exchange blog? Or is someone from Stack Exchange willing to comment?)
- If (as I've tended to assume in the past) model 1 is the intended model but model 2 is what tends to happen in practice, then is this an issue that should be addressed? And if so how, and by whom?

Comment: Maybe you can add a summary for those who don't want to read your entire question. It's massive.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah, I guess I typed a lot more than I was intending to! I'll have a think about improving the structure of it later on.

Comment: If you read the first paragraph and then the questions they don't really make sense. Maybe you can work on that?

Comment: I think you may be trying to over-formalize something that works well organically within communities as their sites evolve.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm not trying to formalise it so much as make the observation that different communities evolve in different ways, and those ways might not all be equal. Whether it works well or not is a value judgement of course, but nevertheless, that's the topic I'm trying to raise.

Comment: I think you are setting up a false dichotomy and demanding that we choose between them. What if I just want to say "yes"?

Comment: @KateGregory I don't think I'm demanding anything. The two models do seem different to me, both in principle and in practice, but if they seem the same to you then I guess that's no problem for either of us. (Though it doesn't really help me to understand the answer to my question.)

Comment: I don't think they are the same, I just think that "either A or B" is a false dichotomy. Some times people vote based on existing site policy. Other times **the very same people** vote based on what they think policy should change to, often after seeing some particular kind of post for the first time. Some people are always "here is a meta link that proves I am right to vote this way" but not all are. Some people are always "who cares what meta says I think this is right/wrong" but not all are. There is no dichotomy and picking one isn't necessary and wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @KateGregory I'm still not sure why you think I'm setting up a dichotomy between the two approaches. My question is based on an observation that both approaches exist to different degrees in different communities, and a series of observations on the effects that has. I say quite explicitly that "my division of this issue into two distinct camps is probably a massive oversimplification, but hopefully it will help to get the point across". Perhaps the issue is with the summary I was asked to write, which, by virtue of being short, necessarily oversimplifies the point.

Comment: @KateGregory I've removed the summary in case that was the cause of the misunderstanding. (The post was collecting down votes after I added it, so I suspect so.) Another way to put the point is, while sometimes people take one approach to close voting and sometime the other, different communities have different norms about which is seen as acceptable.

Comment: Basically asking if the tail is wagging the dog or if Christopher Guest even needs a script

Comment: @random, why did you close this?  This isn't a duplicate.  That other question is asking about whether individual SE sites can overrule network-wide policy, which is a totally different question.  This question is about the difference between vote-to-close being done based solely on a pre-existing site's closure policies, vs a site's closure policies being built up over time based on a pattern of votes-to-close -- not whether site rules can override network-wide rules.

Comment: Because network-wide rules is the template for new sites until they get their own footing. They either choose to follow established norms (close follows the rules) or they decide what is and isn't in scope over time (rules follow patterns of closure)

Comment: @random yeah, this is not a duplicate. I don't even see it as particularly closely related. The other question is about conflicts between local community rules and global policy, whereas my question is about the way that community norms to develop over time and the way in which that the system is designed to facilitate that.

Answer (score 9):

I think the truth lies somewhere in between. Of course, we only can close questions that are violating the site rules or which are duplicates of previously asked questions. We can't just close questions we don't like, although I agree this sometimes happens. The community could and should correct that.

Some close reasons are open for interpretation. When exactly is a question too broad, or unclear? I may find it unclear but you might think otherwise. This is an area that evolves as you go as a community. Those boundaries are not set in stone, the community will decide every time whether a question fits or not. I think that is okay, we have to judge each post on its merits and often a lot of factors come in play.

Comment: "close questions that are violating the site rules" - not 100% correct. Duplicates violate no rules, and are on topic.

Comment: You are right @sha

Comment: I broadly agree with this, but my point is that when you say "those boundaries are not set in stone", that actually encompasses quite a continuum of different approaches. In some communities, those boundaries are actually written down to quite a large extent, and they change because people discuss them and vote on it. In other communities, those boundaries are defined only on an intuitive level, and I think that's a much worse system.

Comment: But it is very hard to write rules for every question. Sometimes a broad question is just narrowed down enough to make it answerable. Others are just on the other side of the line. That is where interpretation comes in.

Comment: Obviously some level of judgement is unavoidable in practice, but I think the ideal is to minimise it as much as possible. As I said, some communities strive for this to a much larger extent than others.

Comment: True. That will also depend on how mature a site is. Stack Overflow has very clear rules and there is consistency in closing questions. Newer communities are still searching to find what is on-topic and what isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I think a lot depends on the close reason here:

- off-topic: mostly about policy
- opinion-based, broad, and unclear: more about judging questions on a continuum. Some things can be determined by policy, but there'll likely always be some gray area.
- duplicates: not really much policy at all

For controversial off-topic subjects, you basically have to sort it out on meta. Trying to decide that using close/reopen votes would be a nightmare, but meta allows for the discussion and community voting you need. Then people with close privileges have an obligation to enforce that policy with their votes.

For fuzzier things like opinion-based, broad, and unclear, it makes sense to have some push and pull. In most cases, votes can be used to both determine and enforce the policy. But when something controversial comes up, you go off and discuss on meta, which then helps calibrate people's standards for enforcement.

The only way to really do it wrong is to try to use votes to try to change a policy that's already been determined. If X has been decided on meta to be off-topic, then votes should be used only to enforce that policy. Folks don't get to restart the debate every time a question comes up. If enough time has passed to warrant reconsidering the decision, meta is the place. If some individuals insist on contradictiong the community's preference, it's reasonable for moderators to step in.